# Php - Form validation - drop down menu + comments box

Tags: php, forms, validation, if-statement

I have been working on a input form for students for the past couple of hours. I have done mostly all of it with 0 hicups but I come across one minor issue that I can't think of a work around for. I have a drop down menu and the validation for that is :

```
 }
        if(empty($why) === true) {
            $errors[] = 'Please make sure to select the proper reasoning for your vistit today!';
    }
```

the default variable is set to be empty or just value="" (empty)...

now the next thing I need to validate is that if the student chooses the option "Other" I need them to then insert at least 10 characters and max of 30 into a Comments box specifically made for the students who can not find the general reason for their visit to the financial aid office. This is what I have for this (it is not working btw) :

```
if(isset($why) === Other) {
        $errors[] = 'Please add a comment explaining why you are visiting the office.';
}
```

So all in all I need help writing a validation that if the student chooses other then he or she MUST then write a brief summary as to why he or she is visiting the office in the "comments box".

Any help would be lovely. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say that the textarea for the 'other' field is called `$other`

```
if(empty($why)){
  $errors[] = 'Please select a reason';
}elseif($why == 'Other' && empty($other)){
  $errors[] = 'You selected Other. Please enter a reason why';
}
```

Your code will probably need to be more detailed than the above since you're looking to set a minimum and maximum number of characters, but you get the jist?

BTW, I see no reason why you would want to use the `===` operator instead of the `==` operator. They do the exact same thing but `===` checks to see if it's the same type, not sure what good this does for your script.

Comment: `if(empty($why)) $errors[] = 'Please make sure to select the proper reasoning for your vistit today!';
  { elseif ($why =='Other' && empty($_POST['comments']))
    $errors[] = 'Please explain the nature of your visit';
}` I'm getting an error from running that code... i swear the answer is slapping me right in the face.

Comment: Take off those brackets `{ }` you dont need them. In PHP you dont need to add brackets after the `if` statement if you are just running one line of code after it.

Comment: Your awesome seriously... thank you so very much. Happy holidays man.

Comment: Glad I could help, same to you

Answer (score 0):

For `if(isset($why) === Other)`, shouldn't *Other* be in quotes since *$why* will return the dropdown menu selection's value as text?

So `if(isset($why) === 'Other')` should work assuming that *"Other"* is the name of the dropdown menu's *Other* selection option.

Edit: Looking at your code again, you are comparing an `isset()` value to another var (Other). 
You want to have it as `if(isset($why) && $why === 'Other')` so this way you check that *$why* is set and it also equals the text *"Other"*. The === operator is also checking to see if $why and Other are of the same type so you should check the rest of your code to make sure *$why* and *Other* are of same type.